# Rails Routes redirect to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rails-routing

I would like all urls of the type www.mysite.co.za/learning/*
to resolve to http://learning.mysite.co.za/*

I can get them to resolve to just http://learning.mysite.co.za using

```
match '/learning/*other', :to => redirect('http://learning.getsmarter.co.za/'), via: 'get'
```

but how do I get the *other to append to that.

e.g.
www.mysite.co.za/learning/blah/blah

to

learning.mysite.co.za/blah/blah

Does that make sense?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the dynamic segment with `%{other}`:

```
match '/learning/*other', :to => redirect('http://learning.getsmarter.co.za/%{other}'), via: 'get'
```

Comment: Thats great. But for more than one segment it produces something like this: http://learning.mysite.co.za/blah%2Fblah2%2Fblah3

Comment: I found the solution. This did the trick: `match '/learning/:other', :to => redirect{ |params| "http://learning.mysite.co.za/#{params[:other]}" }, via: 'get', :constraints => {:other => /.*/}`

Comment: Can't you drop the constraint? Isn't it saying anything zero or more times?